# How to show fields id and name from SQL table to combobox of C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I would like to retrieve the value of fields 'Id' and 'name' of a SQL table show in a `combobox`, this is what I got so far:

```
public void LoadComboboxSite()
{
    List<SITE> bp = new List<SITE>();
    bp = BUS.BUS_Site.compoboxSite();
    for (int i = 0; i < bp.Count; i++)
    {
        cmbSite.Items.AddRange(bp[i].ID_SITE, bp[i].TEN_SITE);
    }

    cmbSite.SelectedItem = bp[0].ID_SITE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of data from your database just use:

```
cmbSite.DisplayMember = "TEN_SITE";
cmbSite.ValueMember = "ID_SITE";
cmbSite.DataSource = bp;
```

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: @jacky_huynh your are welcome..is the code solve your problem?

Comment: @Ortund I use it before but as long as i use EF when use `Combobox.DataSource = entity.ToList();` its not need to `cmbSite.DataBind()`..do you know why?

Comment: @combo_ci I don't actually. Maybe someone else can tell us.